# Adding text animation in the middle of two video layers with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation

I am wondering, How to add text Animation(with CALayer or something like that) in the middle of two or more video layers(order of z index). (like,  video layer -> text animation layer ->  video layer).

I know how to merge two or multiple video(with avfoundation & metal). But I want to put text animation in between two videos.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You need to show us at least what you've tried so far.